# How to setup AWS alarms to send notification in both going on and off?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I have an alarm set on Lambda iterator age, when it crosses X over 5 minutes, It goes to alarm and I send e-mail to a certain group.

Problem I have is - how to, or where to - setup notification for when alarm is resolved.

We have occasional blips which last only a few minutes more than the alarm itself (e.g. 6-7 minutes) and yes, I could extend and not trigger the alarm, but I'd love to get "Alarm is now resolved" e-mail rather than having people dropping everything and jumping on the problem.

I don't see that option, I tried to copy the same alarm and set it "inverted"

[image: off alarm]

But now this guy is "always on" end "Red" which is not what I want.

And I have the proper Alarm that is currently "not in alarm" and which works as Intended:

[image: Proper Alarm set]

So, what are my options here? Do I need composite alarm somehow?

Answer (score 4):

If anyone arrives with the same problem. In late 2021.

AWS UI is not the greatest, so my initial thought was that "Add notification" means, add existing configuration. Sort of "apply".

[image]

Turns out, that's the place where you need to add another notification, or multiple ones, e.g. one for OK, one for Insufficient data behaviour.

Just in case anyone ends up with the same problem.